# PHP wrong approximation with printf

Tags: php, printf, approximation

I am fully aware of the floating point representation in binary format, so I know there are mathematical "impossibilities" when trying to perfectly represent a floating point number in any programming language.
However, I would expect a programming language to follow some well known and well established rules when dealing with approximation.

Having said so, I read (here on stackoverflow too) that printf in PHP is probably the best way to "correctly truncate/approximate" a number, and - again - I am fully aware and I can easily code a one-line-function to give me the "perfect" approximation. This is just to avoid answers like "why don't you use XXX or do YYY?".

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $k = 1.50 + $i/1000;
  printf("%f %.2f<br>", $k, $k);
}
```

This is the output:

> 1.500000 1.50
>   1.501000 1.50
>   1.502000 1.50
>   1.503000 1.50
>   1.504000 1.50
>   1.505000 1.50
>   1.506000 1.51
>   1.507000 1.51
>   1.508000 1.51
>   1.509000 1.51

As you can easily see, 1.504 is (correctly) printed as 1.50, and 1.506 is (correctly) printed as 1.51.
But why 1.505 is printed as 1.50?! It MUST BE 1.51, not 1.50!

Thank you...

Comment: 1.505000 is an approximation

Comment: You say you are aware of the binary representation. Try to add another `%.20f` format, and you see why.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Because in math and physics and in all the other languages that I know, from 0-4 you truncate, from 5-9 you round to the next value...

Comment: @user1596143: Well, firstly that depends (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_to_even#Round_half_to_even).  But more importantly, see the comment about `%.20f`...

Comment: @dialer Ok, great, thank you... Geez, what is PHP using?! 4 bytes for a floating point?! I'll delve into that myself, thank you... :)

Comment: @user1596143: The same problem exists no matter how many bytes are used for the floating-point representation.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly round the values using the `round` function, so that you are able to use the argument `mode` with values of:

`PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP -- Round val up to precision decimal places away from zero, when it is half way there. Making 1.5 into 2 and -1.5 into -2.`

`PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN -- Round val down to precision decimal places towards zero, when it is half way there. Making 1.5 into 1 and -1.5 into -1.`

function:

`float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )`

see full description:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

EDIT:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $k = 1.50 + $i/1000;
  printf("%f %f<br>", $k, round($k,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP));
}
```

Comment: But does it give the result the OP expects?  The real problem is that (s)he doesn't actually have 1.505...

Comment: It doesn't require the `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP`, though. OP's issue was something else; a simple `round($k, 2)` will do.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes it will yield the expected result, because `round` accounts for floating point inaccuracies and can correctly guess what the user really wants, even if the **actual** number is 1.504999999999999999...

Comment: @dialer: Interesting, so the PHP implementers sacrificed correctness!  Nevertheless, I wonder how robust that is.  From a quick read of https://wiki.php.net/rfc/rounding, it sounds like they did the usual PHP thing of just adding hacks upon hacks until it sort of worked...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth "adding hacks upon hacks until it sort of worked"... Welcome to the world of professional software development :D

Comment: @sharp12345 Thank you for that, I didn't know it. Still, it doesn't answer my question. "By default", from 0 to 4 you MUST round "down", from 5 to 9 you MUST round "up", it's a mathematical, physical, statistical way to do it, because if you keep doing like PHP, rounding a large amount of number will not be "even" (because in 60% of the cases, you truncate, and only in 40% of the cases, you round it up: it should be, like everywhere else, 50/50)

Comment: @user1596143: Always rounding halves up will definitely not give up an "even" result; it introduces a statistical bias.  That's why things like round-to-even exist.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I do not want to go off topic and I thank you for answering, but I do not get it. If we assume we have a randomly distributed set of floating point numbers that we want to approximate, it seems logical (to me ;) to expect that they will have e.g. the third digit after the "point" evenly distributed between 0 and 9, so if you want to keep an "even" approximation, you must truncate 50% of them "down", and round 50% of them "up", and since we have 10 digits, we should truncate digits 0,1,2,3,4 down and digits 5,6,7,8,9 up. Where is the statistical bias? It looks even to me ;)

Comment: @user1596143  0 (zero) is not approximated, 1,2,3,4 down, 6,7,8,9 up, 5 is biased