# Count how many pages are needed

Tags: c#

How do I count how many pages my data needs to fit?

I got 23 rows of data and every page takes 20 rows = 2pages.

**When I divide it, I get 1:**

```
var pages = totalRows / 20;
```

**When I use modulus, I get 3:**

```
var pages = totalRows % 20;
```

So please explain to me what calculation I should use to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is based on database rows and you want to see how many pages you need for an X amount of rows per page?

Comment: Why don't you start by thinking through how you determined that you needed 2 pages?

Comment: Allendar, no. 
I want to scrape a website of content and i need to know how many pages there is.

Answer (score 6):

You should divide and then round up, which will account for a final page that has less than 20 rows.

```
var pages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRows / 20.0);
```

Comment: This problem can and should be resolved with only integer arithmetic.

Comment: Because of the same thing that happend to [this person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717913/php-wrong-approximation-with-printf).

Comment: @dialer That is not relevant to this answer. Any result of division that has a fractional component will be rounded up when using `Math.Ceiling`.

Comment: It is relevant to this answer. Every floating point representation is an approximation. Evalute this in C#: `Math.Ceiling(7.525 / 1.505)`.

Comment: @dialer We are not at all dealing with a fractional row count in this case. I challenge you to, instead of coming up with contrived examples that do not relate to this answer, come up with a value of `totalRows` that results in an incorrect computation of `pages`.

Comment: Or if you prefer, use `20m` as the divisor instead of `20.0`.  (`csharp> Math.Ceiling(7.525m / 1.505m); --> 5`)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var pages = (totalRows+19) / 20;
```

in general:

```
var pages = (totalRows+rowsPerPage-1) / rowsPerPage;
```

that is equivalent to doing a floating point division and rounding up (see other answer)

Answer (score 0):

I like cdhowie's answer. But if you don't want to use `Math.Ceiling` you can do the following:

```
int pages = totalRows / 20;
if (totalRows % 20 != 0) { pages += 1; }
```